# VueJS how to set value of feColorMatrix

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

In my Vue Project i have a component called demo.vue.

Said component contains a rather complex `svg` in its `<template>`.
Now @click on one of said elements, the Javascript should change the color of one of the svg's dropshadows.

The svg is a design exported from Figma and i figured out that the dropshadow i want to change the color of is set as follows:

```
<feColorMatrix id="dropshadowID" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0.233333 0 0 0 0 0.233333 0 0 0 0.25 0" result="hardAlpha"/> //Displays a red dropshadow
```

The code for the color i want to achieve would look like this:

```
<feColorMatrix id=dropshadowID type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.233333 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0.31 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
```

I tried to approach it like this:

**Javascript**

```
function changeDropshadow() {
    var target = document.getElementById('dropshadowID')
    target?.classList.add('greenShadow')
}
```

**CSS**

```
.greenShadow {
    values="0 0 0 0 0.233333 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0.31 0 0 0 0.25 0"
}
```

However, CSS does not know the `values` property.
That leaves me with the following question:

How can i change the color of my dropshadow in Javascript with the click of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign your values to a variable and update it in the Vue code

```html
// template
<feColorMatrix id="dropshadowID" type="matrix" :values="values" result="hardAlpha"/>

<script setup>
const values = ref('0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0.233333 0 0 0 0 0.233333 0 0 0 0.25 0')
function changeDropshadow() {
    values.value = "0 0 0 0 0.233333 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0.31 0 0 0 0.25 0"
}

</script>
```

[Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)